# What is the best way to make String(including line breakers from text view) for JSON format in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm making an IOS app which has composing post function.
User types their text through UITextView instance and can include line breakers.
And the app send the post to rails server.
The http body (content type : application/json, name: String, text: String ) looks like below :

```
"{\"name\":\"\(name)\", \"text\":\"\(text)\"}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

The problem is "\n".
If the text including "\n" the rails server raise parse error because JSON accepts "\\n" but not "\n".
So I need to change all "\n" in text to "\\n" before making JSON form, and I think it is very bad way.

I believe there are better ways like 'built-in methods for changing string to JSON form' or 'text view settings' or 'making http body in other ways'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to create JSON on iOS is to create an object that can be serialized into JSON (`NSDictionary` or `NSArray`) and use the NSJSONSerialization methods to convert it into data you can send to a server.

In your example, I would do the following:

```
let obj = ["name": name, "text": text]
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj, options: .PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
```

That should do all the necessary work for you.